# change HTML code for fading background replacing images

Tags: javascript, html

This is my HTML code:

```html
    
<html>
<head>

<script language="JavaScript">
<!--
// Set speed (milliseconds)
var speed = 4000

// Specify the image files
var Pic = new Array() // don't touch this
// to add more images, just continue
// the pattern, adding to the array below

Pic[0] = 'img_1.jpg'
Pic[1] = 'img_2.jpg'
Pic[2] = 'img_3.jpg'
Pic[3] = 'img_4.jpg'

// =======================================
// do not edit anything below this line
// =======================================

var t
var j = 0
var p = Pic.length

var preLoad = new Array()
for (i = 0; i < p; i++){
   preLoad[i] = new Image()
   preLoad[i].src = Pic[i]
}

function runBGSlideShow(){
   if (document.body){
   document.body.background = Pic[j];
   j = j + 1
   if (j > (p-1)) j=0
   t = setTimeout('runBGSlideShow()', speed)
   }
}

//-->
</script>
</head>
<body onload="runBGSlideShow()">

</body>
</html>
```

I tried everything I know to change it so the pictures will fade when replacing but I didn't succeed.
If you can I will appreciate it if you will add to the HTML code (if can't it's ok to add css )
Please look and see if you can help me.

Comment: It will be helpful if you edit your question and add an example of something you tried.

Answer (score 0):

Why reinvent the wheel?

There's a beautiful jQuery plugin that does this already

http://srobbin.com/jquery-plugins/backstretch/